# MobX with React

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I am new to MobX with React. So wanted to practice a bit. I created a project with Create React App. I have my package.json as

```
{
   "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
        "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.2.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.2",
        "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
        "css-loader": "2.1.1",
        "dotenv": "6.2.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.2",
        "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
        "jest": "24.9.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
        "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
        "mobx": "^5.15.1",
        "mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
        "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
        "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
        "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.11.0",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
        "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
        "react-router": "^5.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "resolve": "1.12.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
        "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
        "semver": "6.3.0",
        "source-map-explorer": "^2.0.1",
        "style-loader": "1.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
        "ts-pnp": "1.1.4",
        "url-loader": "2.1.0",
        "webpack": "4.41.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
        "flow-bin": "^0.111.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react-app"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            ["transform-decorators-legacy", { "legacy": true, "decoratorsBeforeExport": false }]
        ]
    }

}
```

But this is throwing me an error as below

[image]

I searched online. Everywhere it is showing to add the above options like legacy, decoratorsBeforeExport, but still no luck. I tried removing all the options, keeping one at a time and the above config also for babel plugins. Still, I am getting this issue.

Comment: Probably want to use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators since you're using a newer version of Babel

Comment: So, should this new dependency be used along with transform-decorators-plugin or in place of that?

Comment: Use that in place of the transform-decorators-plugin :)